# dll error when calling a method of a .dll that includes Opencv dependency

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, wrapper, opencv3.0

I have c++ project compiled as dll. I have set all necessay include and library directories, and compiles fine.

Then, this .dll file is called by another project, but crashes because there is not able to find the opencv dependency.
The dll project has an `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`. And it seems that is not able to find the opencv dependencies.

Context:

- Opencv include folder is at `C:\opencv\build\include`
  I had set it to `VC++ directories`.
- For `VC++ directories -> Library directories`, I added `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib`
- In C/C++, I also added the include path to `Additional Include Directories`
- In `Linker -> General`, I added `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib` to `Additional Library directories`.
- In `Linker -> Input`, I added `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib\opencv_world330d.lib` to `Additional dependencies` (I am compiling in debug mode).

Any additional required info, please let me know.

Comment: Where does `C#` come into the picture?

Comment: If the dll is built, then it is not a matter of your build settings. You need to copy the opencv dlls to the output folder (where your exe is). You can do it either manually or with a post-build command.

Comment: The C# comes into picture because is the project from where I call the dll. If it cares, I can post the wrapper code. But if not, just avoid this info. thx

Comment: aha, a postbuid event, in my case, for the opencv_world330d into the same folder, was the solution. Thank you @wohlstad

Comment: Since C# doesn't have anything to do with the question, I removed it.

Comment: @Jaume good to hear. Note that for _Release_ builds, you need the opencv dlls without the `d` suffix (which stands for _Debug_).